# How to install Dropbox in Windows 7 for all user accounts?

Tags: installation, dropbox

That's it. When installing Dropbox on my laptop it's only installed for my current user account, the other users can't see the shortcuts or use them (since logged in as another user the shortcuts always point to the dropbox of the user that installed it). How do you install it so all other accounts can use their own dropbox?

Comment: I just wonder, is this feasible? In order to install dropbox you need a dropbox account, while users should not know about each other's account. It comes natural that each user will have to install his/her own dropbox. Well it's annoying, but I'm not sure whether dropbox support that.

Comment: They should support it. I don't need to know anything about another local user's Dropbox account to use my own or vice versa. The problem is they defaulted to per user *installation* instead of an option for a system wide installation paired with per user *settings* that would specify the Dropbox account, local Dropbox folder, etc. for each user. It's just bad design and nothing else. We don't install Microsoft Outlook for each user simply because they use different email accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) offers an [AddOn](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons) called [DropBoxen](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons/dropboxen) that can accomplish what you are trying to do:

> Dropboxen enables you to run multiple Dropbox clients concurrently by
>   automatically launching multiple instances of Dropbox.exe as different
>   Windows users so Dropbox will store the shared files in each unique
>   Windows user directory.

It's not ideal and there are some specific problems and workarounds with trying to use this on Windows 7, but if you really want to accomplish this, its possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.  The Dropbox installer does not offer you the option to change the install location and it doesn't install to the Program Files directory.  It installs to the current user's AppData directory, which is not accessible by other users.  On Windows 7, that would be someplace like this:

`C:\Users\raven\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox`

Comment: Does that means that each user must install it on their account profile or that doing so will override the current dropbox account in use and therefore it can only exist 1 dropbox account per computer?

Comment: @Fellknight: This means that each user gets their own personal installation of Dropbox in their user folder.  Every user can have a Dropbox account.

Comment: @raven "every user can have a Dropbox account" has absolutely no relationship with why Dropbox is not installed in Program Files or a custom directory. The roaming profile is supposed to be used for settings, not application installations. Settings should be sufficient for account separation. By bloating it with executables, Dropbox are just making roaming profiles (as used in e.g. Windows accounts on domains) take longer to sync.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported by default.  Each Windows user can have a separate dropbox account set up on one device.

Excerpt from here: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/61

> For our advanced users
>
> If you're a Dropbox Basic or Dropbox Pro user, it's also possible to
>   use a different Dropbox account for each user login on your computer.
>   While this technically means you can have several Dropbox folders on
>   the same computer, you'll have to switch between each user account to
>   take advantage of Dropbox's syncing features. This method is best for
>   groups or families that have individual Dropbox accounts and use
>   unique user logins on the same computer.

Dropbox now installs to this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client